# Prime number finder C#

Tags: c#

So I wrote a programm to check if the entered number by user is prime or not. So far it works, but I olso need to change it in order to also print every prime number until the one given by user.

Here is my C# code:

```
using System;

public class PrimeNumberExample
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n, i, m = 0, flag = 0;
        Console.Write("Prime number finder, enter your number below:  ");
        n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        m = n / 2;
        for (i = 2; i <= m; i++)
        {
            if (n % i == 0)
            {
                Console.Write("Is not a prime number.");
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (flag == 0)
            Console.Write("Is a prime number.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did write something on the mater years ago on MSDN. Particular in relation the Multitasking and -threading. Afaik, it is still good: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/85fc2406-d2e9-495a-bea7-e516661f8b40/primal-issues-multithreading-lists-in-memory-and-checking-for-prime-number?forum=csharpgeneral | What you have there, is what I picked as Nr. 5. | For your goal, I think Nr1. is the only real solution. Remember the part where you can grow the "list of known primes" via calculation,

Comment: what have _you_ tried? where do _you_ have difficulty?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  your code is fairly inefficient, given it works from i is 2 to half the value of the number, and repeats for every  number  including evens which you already know is not a valid prime.  So is doing twice as many calculations as it needed to.   I

Comment: To print every number until the one given by the user. you can use another for loop on the top.

Comment: The best option for finding prime numbers between 1 and a user-supplied number is to use a **sieve**. Articles discussing the theory, algorithm(s), and code examples can be found easily.

Comment: Many thanks for all the help, I really apreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Console.Write("Prime number finder, enter your number below:  ");
int i, j, n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
bool isPrime = false;

for (i = 2; i <= n; i++)
{
    isPrime = true;

    for (j = 2; j < (i / 2); j++)
    {
        if (i % j == 0)
        {
            isPrime = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (isPrime)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{i} Is a prime number.");
    }
}

if (!isPrime)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{n} Is not a prime number.");
}
```

Comment: Your solution worked just fine. Thank you very much kind stranger.

Answer (score 0):

Check the code for the comments indicating the start and end of the additional code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int n, i, m = 0, flag = 0;
    Console.Write("Prime number finder, enter your number below:  ");
    n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    m = n / 2;
    for (i = 2; i <= m; i++)
    {
        if (n % i == 0)
        {
            Console.Write("Is not a prime number.");
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }

        //Start added code
        bool flagPrime = true;
        for (int x = 2; x <= i; x++)
        {
            if (i % x == 0)
                flagPrime = false;
        }
        if (flagPrime)
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        //End added code
    }

    if (flag == 0)
        Console.Write("Is a prime number.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the prime numbers within a range of numbers

```
public static void Main()
{
int num,i,ctr,stno,enno;

Console.Write("\n\n");
Console.Write("Find the prime numbers within a range of numbers:\n");
Console.Write("---------------------------------------------------");
Console.Write("\n\n");      

Console.Write("Input starting number of range: ");
stno = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());     
Console.Write("Input ending number of range : ");
enno = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());     
Console.Write("The prime numbers between {0} and {1} are : \n",stno,enno);

for(num = stno;num<=enno;num++)
   {
     ctr = 0;

     for(i=2;i<=num/2;i++)
        {
         if(num%i==0){
             ctr++;
             break;
         }
    }

     if(ctr==0 && num!= 1)
         Console.Write("{0} ",num);
}
Console.Write("\n");
```

}